# Burninate / blacklist the [stackoverflow] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, burninate-request

Currently quite a few questions regarding StackOverflow itself, some appropriate and some belonging on Meta, being asked on StackOverflow using the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag. The [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag of course refers to a stack overflow, not the website (there's [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) for that).

My proposed solution is that we remove [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) completely (and possibly blacklist it, so this problem doesn't repeat itself), since there's already [stackoverflowexception](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) and [stackoverflowerror](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) (which we should probably synonymize, since we probably don't need one for each language, or do we?).

Comment: I say we burn all four tags, they all don't have a real purpose, especially when we apply the rule "every tag needs to be able stand on it's own".

Answer (score 6):

I don't see the need to blacklist the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag at all. Almost all [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tagged with stackoverflow are related to a stack overflow. I do, however, think [stackoverflowexception](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception) and [stackoverflowerror](/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror) should be synonyms of [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) itself.

Comment: I myself have changed [tag:stackoverflow] to [tag:stackoverflow.com] on at least a few dozen questions (along with close votes where appropriate, of course), not to mention everyone else and all the migrated questions, who knows what the total numbers are.

Comment: I think that the similarity of `stackoverflow` to the name of the actual website precludes the synomymisation of `stackoverflowexception` and `stackoverflowerror` to `stackoverflow`. Instead, I'd think that `stackoverflowexception` should be the one to stay (as `stackoverflowerror` could be ambiguous regarding its use for errors on the Stack Overflow website).